# What's the cause for an ORA-00979 on oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Trying to understand the use of `GROUP BY` in SQL

I've been crossing several times with this error, and I could have not been able to identify the core in order to solve it in further times

```
SELECT d.department_name
FROM departments d
JOIN employees e
ON (d.department_id = e.department_id)
GROUP BY d.department_name
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees) > 5
AND e.commission_pct IS NOT NULL;
```

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, condition should be in where clause and having shouldn't re-select values

```
 SELECT d.department_name
 FROM departments d
 JOIN employees e
 ON (d.department_id = e.department_id)
 WHERE e.commission_pct IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY d.department_name
 HAVING COUNT(*)  > 5 ;
```

See [more examples](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/having.php)

Answer (score 2):

Having should have columns which are in group by It is the way its built. So having allows you to either aggregate or manipulate the columns of group by. The reason you got the group by error is you have used a subquery instead of a column of group by or aggregate.

In short, having is similar to where but just that having allows you to filter records of a group unlike where which is used to filter records of the whole table itself

```
    SELECT d.department_name
   FROM departments d
    JOIN employees e
    ON (d.department_id = 
      e.department_id)
     Where
      e.commission_pct IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY d.department_name
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 5
   ;
```